# Meaning of ORIG on the first line (16 bits) of LC3

Tags: assembly, binary, lc3

What does the first line of an LC3 code mean?
Does it refer to the initial value of PC or does it point the location in the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to `ORIG`, yes, it defines the address of the first instruction (i.e. all instructions following will incrementally offset from the value specified in .ORIG), and ORIG also sets the initial value of the `Location Counter` (LC, although LC seems to be used interchangeably with PC), i.e. this is where your program will commence execution.

From [this reference document](https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmpe012/Winter09/lectures/06_LC3_Assembly.pdf):

```
.ORIG
- Tells simulator where to put your code in memory (starting location)
- Only one .ORIG allowed per program module
- PC is set to this address at start up
- Similar to the main() function in C
- Example: the standard convention is
  .orig x3000
```

Comment: And I guess just to note that ORIG itself however doesn't directly map to an executable opcode.